# Scala Performant Filter Subsets in same lists

Tags: performance, scala, collections

I am filtering a Set, based on the other values of the same Set, more exactly, filter out the sets that are fully included in another set

```
Set(Set(1, 2), Set(1, 3), Set(1, 4), Set(1, 2, 3))
```

This would result in :

```
Set(Set(1, 4), Set(1, 2, 3))
```

1,2 and 2,3 being fully included in the last set (Basically, I want only the biggest subsets of the lot)

I have come up with this bit of code, which does the trick :

```
def filterIncluded(data: Set[Set[Int]]): Set[Set[Int]] = {  
  data.filterNot{ s =>
    data.exists(x => x.size > s.size && s.forall(x.contains))
  }
}
```

It works great, except for one problem : It is extremely inefficient, my actual dataset will have millions of sets which can each have 2 to 100 values in each

Is there any way to make this go faster? (Using another type of collection, different method calls, changing the way it loops, etc.)

Comment: There are probably other/better solutions, but an idea: if you can change your outer `Set` to a sorted collection (by the size of the inner `Set`s), you could check only `Set`s bigger than the current one. `Set` also has a `subsetOf()` method which is probably faster than `s.forall(x.contains)`.

Comment: @Marth, then again (from the Scala library source) `def subsetOf(that: GenSet[A]): Boolean = this forall that` :) ( `x.contains` is equivalent to `x.apply` for sets, so this is the same as the OP's test). Using `subsetOf` is more intention-revealing, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can't do better than N^2 because you are searching for collisions in a much bigger space that isn't constrained in any sort of regular way.

But you probably are *not* solving the problem in general.  There's probably a particular structure to your data.

For instance, if the numbers are approximately random, you can count the number of occurrences of each number; if a number appears only once, the set which contains it must not be a strict subset.  If you have only a small number, just brute force the search as you did above, and you'll know which are unique.  If you start getting a large number of sets with that distinguishing number (not likely if the numbers are approximately random, but let's say you do), you can subdivide again based on a second number.  Using your example:

```
data.toList.flatMap(_.toList).groupBy(identity).map{ 
  case (k,vs) => k -> vs.length
}
// Gives counts: 1 -> 4, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1
// Pick out the set with a 4: it is unique
// Pick out sets with a 2: Set(1, 2), Set(1, 2, 3)
// Run your algorithm to discard Set(1,2)
// Pick out sets with a 3: Set(1, 3), Set(1, 2, 3)
// Run your algorithm to discard Set(1,3)
// Pick out sets with a 1: only Set(1, 2, 3) remains, keep it
```

Alternatively, if you *could* have any Int but in practice tend to have a bunch of similar numbers, you can build the set equivalent of a suffix tree.  Start with a set which is the union of all your numbers.  Then for each element, list every set which has that element.  Then, under that list, break it down again by a second element.  Any time you get to a level where you actually have the full set, and the list is nonempty, you can discard the full set.

```
1 -> Set(1, 2, 3), Set(1, 2), Set(1, 3), Set(1, 4)
  2 -> Set(1, 2, 3), Set(1, 2)
    But we're _at_ 1,2 so
      throw away Set(1, 2)
      only Set(1, 2, 3) is left--keep it
  3 ->  Set(1, 2, 3); Set(1, 3)
    We're at 1,3 so
      throw away Set(1, 3)
      the other set is already kept
  4 -> Set(1, 4)
    Oh, there's only one.  Keep it.
```

Comment: Ooo, this is a good idea, my data will actually be Longs, since the sheer amount of numbers (and some randomness), so this might be a great solution, I'll try it out and keep you posted

Comment: I've tried this method, and it about halves the time, which is perfect, I"ll try to optimize it even more, but this pretty much solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first improvement I can think of would be:

```
def filterIncluded(data: Set[Set[Int]]): Set[Set[Int]] = {
    val undecided = data.toList.sortBy(_.size).reverse

    undecided.foldLeft(List.empty[Set[Int]]){ case (goodSets, s) =>
        if(goodSets.forall(goodSet => !s.forall(goodSet contains _))) s :: goodSets
        else goodSets
    }.toSet
  }
```

Sorting is NLogN, but then you only have to compare each element to ones that are already proven good since you can only be a proper subset of a set that is larger or the same size. It's still N^2 but slightly more efficient that your original I think.

Alternatively you could do this more complicated thing which actually sounds like that other fellow's answer where you maintain a map of element to good sets which include it. Then when checking a new set you can just get the sets which include the first element and then for each subsequent element you get which sets have that one and take the intersection until either you have an empty intersection (nothing is a superset) or you run out of elements (everything left is a superset). Here is a possibly ugly implementation:

```
  def filterIncluded(data: Set[Set[Int]]): Set[Set[Int]] = {
    def isGood(s: Set[Int], goodSets: Map[Int, Set[Set[Int]]]): Boolean = goodSets.get(s.head) match {
      case None => true
      case Some(sets) => _isGood(s.tail, sets, goodSets)
    }

    def _isGood(s: Set[Int], potentialSupersets: Set[Set[Int]], goodSets: Map[Int, Set[Set[Int]]]): Boolean = {
      // println(s"s($s)\npotentialSupersets($potentialSupersets)\ngoodSets($goodSets)\n")
      goodSets.get(s.head) match {
        case None => true
        case Some(sets) =>
          (s.tail.isEmpty, potentialSupersets & sets) match {
            case (true, remaining) if remaining.nonEmpty => false
            case (false, remaining) if remaining.nonEmpty => _isGood(s.tail, remaining, goodSets)
            case _ => true
          }
        }
    }

    def addToGoodSets(s: Set[Int], goodSets: Map[Int, Set[Set[Int]]]): Map[Int, Set[Set[Int]]] = {
      s.foldLeft(goodSets){case (g, i) => g + (i -> (g.getOrElse(i, Set.empty)+s))}
    }

    val undecided = data.toList.sortBy(_.size).reverse
    // println("UNDECIDED: "+undecided)

    undecided.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Set[Set[Int]]]){ case (goodSets, s) =>
      if(isGood(s, goodSets)) addToGoodSets( s, goodSets)
      else goodSets
    }.values.flatten.toSet
  }
```

I honestly am having a bit of a problem analyzing when this is better than anything else, but there you go. Can you tell I'm bored?

Comment: If you have reason to believe many of your sets will have unique elements then you could maintain a set of all elements seen so far and first compare against that one which would short circuit checking each good set separately.

Comment: Great idea, there will be many unique elements, so this might increase the performance, I'll test it out soon